# Testing for Association in RxC Contingency Tables with 1 Ordinal Variable

Tags: chi-squared-test, ordinal-data, contingency-tables

I'm currently trying to analyze data similar to the following example:

> Suppose I have count data from a survey of US States (~10) relating to
> their population's feelings about how their current state government
> has been doing since their election. This variable is ordinal ("Made
> things somewhat/a lot worse, things are about the same, made things
> somewhat/a lot better").

I'd like to be able to firstly find out if there is an association between state and this ordinal variable and, if there is an association, make conclusions to the effect of "X Y Z are the states have been doing worse/better than would be expected if there was no association".

I know a chi-squared test accomplishes the first task, but since the likert variable is ordinal I feel like this could be "leaving something on the table" in terms of the results I could get. Similarly, I'm aware I could analyze the residuals of the chi-squared test to accomplish the second task, but I feel like this suffers from the same issue as above.

I'm also concerned about keeping this analysis relatively simple if possible, as the audience is not statistically-adept.

|  | Maine | Vermont | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Improved | 52 | 104 | ... |
| Unchanged | 14 | 42 | ... |
| Worsened | 204 | 213 | ... |

Comment: Can you show us the table? Maybe look into ordinal regression, search this site, there are many good posts!

Comment: I added a table. My question about ordinal regression is:would this detect the non-linear trends? As in, imagine that in all states but 1, most people select "unchanged" and two equally sized (but small) groups select "improved" or "worsened", BUT in the 1 particular "outlier" state, two equally sized large groups select "improved" and "worsened" and only a tiny group selects "unchanged".I.e. "most states are very indifferent to the question, but 1 state is very opinionated in their answers". All states would have a "mean" near "unchanged",but clearly this 1 state is different than the others.

Comment: Examining the residuals of the chi-squared test would show "in this 1 state, Improved and Worsened are much higher than expected", and could thus show non-linear trends.